# c++ function return type at compile time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing some non-template c++ functions where a standard identifier for the current function's return type would allow the code to

1. be more expressive
2. be copy/paste-able into another function with a different return type without by-hand modification
3. be resilient against trivial modifications to the function return type

Specifically, I'd like to be able to express

```
std::string Foo::bar()
{
   /*?? what type here??*/ ret;
   ....
   return ret;
}
```

and then be able to copy the function body into a different function **with a different name** that has a **different** return type with similar semantics.

Is there a standard or Visual Studio 2015 specific way to do this?

I don't believe anything at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx helps me, as all macros around function decomposition are expressed as string literals.

Comment: The question was "and then be able to copy the function body into a different function that has a return type with similar semantics."

Comment: "Similar semantics" being what? You want a type that any string type can be constructed from?

Comment: similar semantics - like trivially constructable and copyable T, so I could copy the original body into a new function 'int Foo::baz' without modification.

Comment: ... The obvious solution is to ditch `ret` and just return early. There, no need to contort your code

Comment: I'm not following - return early?

Comment: @kkost: You can `return {}` for example to return the default value of whatever type.  Or `return {123}` to return a value constructed from an integer, regardless of the type (so long as it can be so constructed).

Comment: Return early. Replace each `ret = whatever;` with `return whatever;`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck return {} is actually super close to what I need (not perfect but good enough). write it up top level and I'll give you the accepted answer.

Comment: @kkost: OK, I added `return {}` to my answer.

Comment: @KillzoneKid auto won't work here because the function signature is already defined and invariant to the problem. I like the return {} solution. thanks, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought you should use `decltype()`:

```
decltype(bar()) ret;
```

But then I realized you want to be able to copy-paste the code into another function whose name might be different.  So it's not going to work.

I think in general there is no solution to this.  `__func__` won't help you because it is a string, and you cannot invoke it (`decltype(__func__())` is not valid).

If you just want to return a default-constructed value, you can always do this:

```
return {}; // or put some other constructor argument(s) inside {}
```

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well. Thanks for the thoughts. I really would like this to work - it's similar to auto to me: the compiler _knows_ the type, and I have to play guessing games to make sure I get the right answer.

Comment: @kkost: The elephant in this room is *"Why do you have a hard requirement that the entire body of your functions must be copy-pastable?"*  Maybe if you can answer that we could come up with something useful.

Comment: Not a hard requirement, as copy/paste with type modification is fine, and notepad++ with macros is awesome. This would allow me to create a mock for testing a heck of a lot easier. Also, it bugs me that the compiler knows the right answer already (like auto above).

Comment: @kkost: Sounds like it might be a case for code generation.  That's how I deal with it when I can express the code needing to be written using a program.

Comment: Possibly, but it's not _that_ big of a class, and it will have a long lifetime with many transformations and other programmers fingers in it - I'm trying to prevent future-Murphy with those transformations. Thanks a ton for your help!